# Email Regex not working for some conditions

Tags: regex, email

My regex is not working for below mention emails. Please help 
Regex
^[a-zA-ZA-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(.[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~]+)*@(?:[a-zA-ZA-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9]+.(?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?.)+a-z0-9?$

Email not working
**localpart@domain** not showing error. Valid email is localpart@domain.com

**domain.domain** not showing error. (@ and local part missing)

**localSpecialCharacters!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@domain.domain**  This should not display error but it is showing invalid email error.

**Invalid€character@domain.domain** not showing error but it should as € not allowed.

**localpart@ àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ.domain**
This is also not working

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: `(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this regex is taking spaces in local part. Also working for special characters like (,),<,> and many other conditions I don't want..

Comment: @Ivar As per my rules I don't think there is regex in question you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having specific rules for my requirement. I found the correct regex for my problem i.e.
^([^.])([a-zA-ZA-zàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9.!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~/-])+([^.])@[a-zA-ZA-zàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9]+([a-zA-ZàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9.-]+([a-zA-Z0-9]))*$

Rules were
**For Email local part:**
1) Latin letters are allowed: A to Z and a to z
2) Number are allowed: 0 to 9
3) Following special characters are allowed: !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~<br>
4) Dot “.” is allowed but must not be the first or the last character and two dots must not appear consecutively.<br>
5) Following Latin characters with diacritics are allowed: àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ<br>
6) Other Latin characters are not allowed including special character other than !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~
7) 64 characters length maximum

**Email domain must match the requirements** for a hostname,
1) a list of dot-separated DNS labels, each label being limited to a length of 63 characters and with the following rules:
2) Latin letters are allowed: A to Z and a to z
3) Number are allowed: 0 to 9
4) Hyphen “-“ is allowed but must not be the first or the last character
 
5) Following Latin characters with diacritics are allowed: àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ
6) Other characters are not allowed
7) Total email address: 256 characters length maximum